# Windows Live Authentication with Sharepoint Question

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, login

I have configured as CBA with Windows Live as instructed here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Post.aspx?id=562.  I think I am very close.  When I visit my site I am redirected to select authentication type. I select Windows Live and then redirected here:

https://login.live-int.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3amydomain%3aint&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmydomain.local%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F

When I enter my credentials, it appears as though something is happening because the login.live page flickers and I see something going on (processing/posting back), but I am not redirected back to my local sharepoint site.

Curious if you can help point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much...

Comment: You are logging into the INT environment of Live (the hostname is live-int.com).

Are the credentials you entering also in the INT environment?

Comment: I created a new account in the live-int.com environment, but it is not letting me log in.  It appears as though it is just circling back when I click on "Sign in".  The page does not give me any kind of message.  Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like configuring SharePoint with Windows Live using the approach Victor Wilen blogged about is not very predictive.

I opted to go with the approach Mike Hacker blogged about here:  http://blog.mikehacker.net/2011/04/21/sharepoint-authentication-using-windows-azure-access-controlpart-1/

This approach appears to provide more functionality.  Also, Mike Hacker's post was fairly easy to follow and configure.